# angular scope change not updating view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-ui-draggable

I've created two directives in angular, each one utilizing jQuery UI's draggable and droppable.  The events of both are working just fine.  Something strange is happening when I try to update a view based on the droppable elements.  The only real difference with the two events is that the draggable 'stop' event fires once, when the draggins stops, while the droppable 'drop' event first for each droppable item that the drag item has dropped over.

(Here's some context: the app is a color browser, where the draggable item is a loupe, and the droppable items are small color swatches in a grid.  The loupe is meant to pick a selection of colors when the dragging stops.)

```
angular.module('colorBrowserApp.directives',[])

.directive('ngDraggable', ['$state', function($state) {

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {


                element.draggable({
                    'containment': 'parent',
                    'stop': function(event, ui) {
                        // when dragging stops, clear the main grid and update with selection
                        scope.$parent.colors = [];
                        scope.$apply(); // this successfully updates the view to show 0 items
                    }
                })
            }
        };
    }])


.directive('ngDroppable', ['$state', function($state) {

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.droppable({
                    'accept': '.loupe',
                    'tolerance': 'touch',  // Draggable overlaps the droppable entirely
                    'drop' : function(event, ui) {

                            console.log(scope.$parent.colors.length); // this shows 400, which is correct
                            scope.$parent.colors = [];
                            scope.$apply();
                            console.log(scope.$parent.colors.length); // this shows 0, which is correct, but the view still holds the 400 items

                    }
                })
            }
        };
    }])
```

Comment: Is there any way you can provide as simple a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) as possible in order to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using `$apply` on 'scope.$parent' instead of 'scope'?